# Why did my SOAP request start returning error

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to make a SOAP request with TNT's webservice, but I'm getting an error and I don't know what to do.

There is my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://ws.tntbrasil.com.br:81/tntws/CalculoFrete?wsdl');
$function = 'calculaFrete';
$parameters = array('calculaFrete' => array('in0' => array(
            'cdDivisaoCliente'                 => 1,
            'cepDestino'                       => '36213000',
            'cepOrigem'                        => '36213000',
            'login'                            => 'gerencia@uaiartesanatos.com.br',
            'nrIdentifClienteDest'             => '00000000000',
            'nrIdentifClienteRem'              => '29026107000190',
            'nrInscricaoEstadualDestinatario'  => '0000000000000',
            'nrInscricaoEstadualRemetente'     => '0030746110022',
            'psReal'                           => 15,
            'senha'                            => '',
            'tpFrete'                          => 'C',
            'tpPessoaDestinatario'             => 'F',
            'tpPessoaRemetente'                => 'J',
            'tpServico'                        => 'RNC',
            'tpSituacaoTributariaDestinatario' => 'CO',
            'tpSituacaoTributariaRemetente'    => 'CO',
            'vlMercadoria'                     => 650.17,
        )));
$result = null;      
$result = $client->__soapCall($function, $parameters);
```

and i'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns0:Server] java.lang.NullPointerException in C:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\index.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\index.php(27): SoapClient->__soapCall('calculaFrete', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tnt\index.php on line 27
```

I've been using it since 2018, but in recent weeks this error has started to occur, does anyone know what is going on ??

I thank you all for your help

Comment: You should first of all properly catch the exception, and check if the exception object contains any more useful info, besides just `java.lang.NullPointerException`. That message apparently comes from the webservice itself, but we can’t possibly tell you why - whether you are sending wrong parameters, or something is broken on their end internally. You should maybe contact their support.

Comment: i've tried catch exception, its just java.lang.NullPointerException,

other strange thing is that webservice works when tested with SoapUi

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the webservice.

`java.lang.NullPointerException` is a exception thrown by Java.

It may be some update that broke the webservice, some new parameter that you are not sending or some wrong parameter.

I suggest you to get in touch with the webservice owners.